# C program that sort strings in a more natural way

Tags: c, sorting

I am trying to write a script that is sorting strings in a natural way. This works fine for:

```
Input:
something something1 something10 10
Result:
10 something something1 something10
```

But if I am trying to sort the following:

```
Input:
something8b something8a something1 something15
```

The script is sorting till the first number and I am getting the following result:

```
Result:
something1 something8b something8a something15
```

But the result I want is:

```
something1 something8a something8b something15
```

The code I am trying is the following:

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int naturalstrcmp(const char **s1, const char **s2);
int main(int argc, char **argv){

  qsort(&argv[1],argc-1,sizeof(char*),
    (int(*)(const void *, const void *))naturalstrcmp);
  while(--argc){
    printf("%s ",(++argv)[0]);
  };
  printf("\n");
}
int naturalstrcmp(const char **s1p, const char **s2p){
  if ((NULL == s1p) || (NULL == *s1p)) {
    if ((NULL == s2p) || (NULL == *s2p)) return 0;
    return 1;
  };
  if ((NULL == s2p) || (NULL == *s2p)) return -1;

  const char *s1=*s1p;
  const char *s2=*s2p;

  do {
    if (isdigit(s1[0]) && isdigit(s2[0])){ 
      int c1 = strspn(s1,"0123456789"); 
      int c2 = strspn(s2,"0123456789");
      if (c1 > c2) {
    return 1;
      } else if (c1 < c2) {
    return -1;
      };

      while (c1--) {
    if (s1[0] > s2[0]){
      return 1;
    } else if (s1[0] < s2[0]){
      return -1;
    }; 
    s1++;
    s2++;
      };
    } else if (s1[0] > s2[0]){
      return 1;
    } else if (s1[0] < s2[0]){
      return -1;
    }; 
    s1++;
    s2++;
  } while ( (*s1!='\0') || (*s2!='\0') );
}```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are incrementing twice s1 and s2, if there is a match, when comparing digits, so you are jumping over the next character after the number.
Perform the last increment inside an else statement.

```
   if (digit...)
      ...
      while (c1--) {
        if (s1[0] > s2[0]){
          return 1;
        } else if (s1[0] < s2[0]){
          return -1;
        }; 
        s1++;
        s2++;
      };
    else if(...) {
    }
    else { 
       s1++;
       s2++;
    }
```